# What does the golden dot after the username in close banners represent?

Tags: support, badges, privileges

Users usually don't have any extra symbol after their names. Only moderators have the diamond symbol. But today I saw a golden dot after a name on a close banner of a question.

What is this and who will have that circle after his/her name?

[image: Imgur]
[image: Imgur]

Comment: Interesting, I never noticed that. Could it be a golden tag badge that allows immediate closing?

Comment: @ByteCommander Same, i wish colors could be allowed here on meta too, wait the original site has colors already on meta

Comment: @StarOS In my view, everything is perfectly colorful. What's your problem?

Comment: Colorful? Only for mods and for the public and mods, the original website's meta. It's black and white the layout, but the pictures are not black/white.

Comment: @StarOS Your thought _may_ be unacceptable, so please post a new question with `feature-request` tag instead of commenting here. If you post a Q many will come forward with their views, If you comment here, only me and Byte will be notified :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a [golden tag badge](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold)! Its owners may cast immediate close votes, just like moderators, on questions with the specific tag. This only applies to duplicate-votes at the moment, though.

Currently, there are only two [tags where golden tag badges exist](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold), which are [command-line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/command-line) and [virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/virtualbox). And of these badge types, only 4 badges were ever awarded on Ask Ubuntu in total yet (Oct 2015)!

Their owners are:

- [**"command-line"** golden tag badge](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/182/command-line):

  - [Radu Rădeanu](https://askubuntu.com/users/147044/radu-r%c4%83deanu)
  - [Oli](https://askubuntu.com/users/449/oli)
  - [Sylvain Pineau](https://askubuntu.com/users/32239/sylvain-pineau)
  - [terdon](https://askubuntu.com/users/85695/terdon)
- [**"virtualbox"** golden tag badge](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/233/virtualbox)

  - [Takkat](https://askubuntu.com/users/3940/takkat).

---

Reference for this:

[Increase close vote weight for gold tag badge holders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865) (Meta StackExchange)

[Ask Ubuntu General Room - Chat transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24369438#24369438)

Comment: Dammit. I'm 300 short of a gold tag.

Comment: They only have this ability on duplicate closures right now, although SE is looking at expanding it.

Comment: @Seth Included that into my answer.

Comment: I remember when Radu used this ability the first time. Last year gold badge size was a bit bigger so I immediately found the related help text.

Comment: The post descibing this feature on the main meta might be a better reference than a chat transcript: [Increase close vote weight for gold tag badge holders](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865)

Comment: @terdon Now that I know it, sure! :)

Comment: I am getting there... 981 :D

Comment: @ ByteCommander I edited the post since @Takkat got gold badge in virtualbox =)..

Comment: @Ravan Thanks. I improved it a bit! :)