# Why most metas aren't colorful to the public, but every meta is colorful for mods?

Tags: support

On a conversation with ByteCommander *[which I understood wrong and who I thought is *]* a mod, he tells me that in every meta he sees colors. But it seems the rest of the public only see black and white, except for the Stack Exchange one. I'm talking about the layout, not the logos, the "able-to-click-text" is not black and white. The only purpose for this is because it is a shadow, but why the kitten do we have to see mostly black and white?

<sub>[... *] was added by ByteCommander for clarification</sub>

Comment: ByteCommander is not a moderator...

Comment: I think  you misinterpreted @Byte comment, [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14458/what-does-the-golden-dot-after-the-username-in-close-banners-represent#comment25867_14458)..He clearly mentioned "In my __view__"

Comment: Oops, can i delete this question then.

Comment: Not with an upvoted answer. The only strongly coloured meta I have seen is the [scifi.se] meta.

Comment: You understood me wrong. I am no mod, just an experienced user. At least currently, who knows what the future will bring...? ;D - But I did not want to say that the design of AU meta is not grey. That's it, I would not have imagined that anybody would question that... Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ByteCommander  :D :D :D  Who knows?  You might end up as a mod one day!!!  **;-)**

Comment: Have a look [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2290/how-does-the-site-look-like-to-a-moderator) @StarOS

Answer (score 8):

I'm pretty sure the meta sites look the same for moderators and non-moderators.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I am not a mod and mine looks `exactly` like this (without the diamond, of course)